# ol numbers underneath li text

Tags: css, html-lists

I'm trying to figure out how to style items in my ol. My goal is for the end result to have the ol horizontal with the numbers under left aligned under the li text.

Example of how end result should look:
Item    Item    Item    Item    Item
1         2        3         4         5

Comment: Will the text always be single words? can the text wrap to 2 or more lines?

Comment: I'd be interested to see the answer for this. I am sure there are workarounds but curious if there is a better

Comment: How are the items currently positioned? Does it matter? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way of realizing this design using pseudo-elements to position a custom counter.

You can start with either an ordered or an unordered list:

```
<ol class="list">
    <li>Apples</li>
    <li>Bananas</li>
    <li>Cherries</li>
    <li>Durian</li>
</ol>
```

apply the following CSS:

```css
.list {
    counter-reset:itemcounter;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.list li {
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    margin-right: 30px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
.list li:after {
    content:counter(itemcounter);
    color:#000;
    counter-increment: itemcounter;
    display: block;
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Define a custom counter and position it in a pseudo-element `li:after`.

I floated the list items to get the horizontal menu but you can also use inline-blocks.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/DgZvg/

**Backwards Compatibility**

The limiting design factor here is the custom counter, which is supported from IE8 going forward: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-counters

### Alternative For Older Browsers

For older browsers that don't support counters and generated content, you could try something like the following.

You need to add a wrapper element on your list content:

```
<ol class="list">
    <li><p>Apples</p></li>
    <li><p>Bananas</p></li>
    <li><p>Cherries</p></li>
    <li><p>Durians</p></li>
</ol>
```

and then apply the following CSS:

```
.list {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.list li {
    list-style-position: inside;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    margin-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 5px; /* gives you some control... */
    float: left;
    padding-top: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.list li p {
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 0;
}
```

In this case, you `list-style-position: inside`, and then define a two-line text region by specifying a line-height of 20px and padding-top of 20px. You also need to specify a width on the list items.

You then set the height to the inner wrapper and then use absolute positioning to offset the bottom by 20px.

This is much more work, a bit constrained because of the width and height lengths, 
but it is a proof-of-concept.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/PUH9V/

Comment: That's exactly what I was creating, haha

Comment: Are there any compatibility issues?  I'm suspicious of IE in particular.

Comment: It doesn't work well on old versions of IE at 8 and before http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent

Comment: It seems to work in everything from IE 8 and above. Pretty elegant solution if you don't need to worry about IE 7.

Comment: And I would say not to worry about IE7 at all.

Answer (score 0):

I used a span inside the li to position the text above the element.  You may need to adjust the CSS to work better in your actual environment.

http://jsfiddle.net/j5Nbx/2/

**HTML**

```
<ol class="example">
    <li>
        <span>Item</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Item</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Item</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Item</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Item</span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
.example li {
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
}

.example:after{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}

.example li span {
    position:relative;
    left:-35px;
    top:-20px;
}
```

Comment: Your and my solution seems similar. Except you used pseudo for clearing floats. Do we really need them?

Comment: Actually, now that you mention it, you would need to add the psudo element after the OL (I have edited my post).  This is because block level elements will still be floated after the OL. See http://jsfiddle.net/fuLjk/1/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/j5Nbx/3/

Comment: Gotcha! seems fine now.

Answer (score 0):

And here is my way, with CSS 2.x and cross browser :)

**HTML**

```
<ol>
    <li><span>item</span></li>
    <li><span>item</span></li>
    <li><span>item</span></li>
    <li><span>item</span></li>
    <li><span>item</span></li>
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
ol li {
    position:relative;
    min-width:100px;
    padding:30px 0 0;
    float:left;
}

ol li span {
    position:absolute;
    left:-30px;
    top:0px;
}
```

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/shekhardesigner/fuLjk/